# Is there a Windows equivalent to Secretive?

Tags: windows, ssh, cryptography

I am looking for a Windows-compatible SSH agent that would utilise the TPM for key management and require Windows Hello confirmation to use a key.
In the Mac world, there is a great SSH agent called [Secretive](https://github.com/maxgoedjen/secretive) that lets you create and store SSH keys in the Mac's Secure Enclave (TPM equivalent) and access them using regular Mac authentication (Touch ID, password, Apple Watch, etc.).
I couldn't find a similar application for Windows. Is there an SSH agent for Windows that can create and use SSH keys in the TPM, and confirm access to them with Windows Hello?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using '[nCryptAgent](https://github.com/unreality/nCryptAgent)' which works with Windows SSH and WSL.